# 415 unsupported mediatype for simple get request with async api

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8

My code is

```
import play.libs.ws.WSClient;
import play.libs.ws.WSResponse;
import play.libs.Json;
import play.libs.ws.WSRequest;
import play.mvc.BodyParser;

public class CouponsController extends Controller {
    @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
    public CompletionStage<Result> test() {
        WSRequest request = ws.url("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");
        CompletionStage<WSResponse> responsePromise = request.get();     
        return responsePromise.thenApply(response-> ok(response.getBodyAsStream()));
    }
}
```

I get error 415 Unsupported Media type response with above code. What is the mistake I am making?

and body contains the error

```
Bad Request
For request 'GET /coupons/test' [Expected application/json]
```

Note:
I removed 
        @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
and it worked

Comment: Try setting the "Accept" header to `application/json`: `request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");` to let the server know you want a JSON response.

Comment: I tried this but its still not working

Comment: How did you try it? Call `request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");` on the `request` object before you call `request.get();`.